# Angular directive templateUrl won't render on script tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-foundation

Originally, I had asked why the partial that I've defined in my controller and ng-template won't populate the modal.

After having no success loading any directive on the script tag - I believe that the routing method we are using is what is circumventing the script from finding the partial.

The directive's templateUrl returns 404 when invoked via the modal ng-click="open()". Everything resolves correctly if invoked on other elements.

Directive loads templateUrl on div:

```
<div data-modal-partial-directive></div>
```

Directive templateUrl returns 404 on script:

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" 
        data-modal-partial-directive>
    </script>

    <button class="button" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
</div>
```

What's even more confounding is that the controller logs that the modal was dismissed. Which means that everything else is running smoothly, except that 404 stops the content from loading, which closes the modal.

Does this sound familiar to anyone's use case? Is there a way around it?

Comment: what are you trying to say here: _"the modal content on shows what's written in the contents"_?

Comment: so where's the scope for the modal controller? We can't guess why scope expressions aren't evaluating other than the properties don't exist in scope and the resolve `items` is being passed in

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clear. It's not a problem with scope, it's where the template is being called from.

Desipte my controller templateUrl settings and type="text/ng-template" both requesting the partial file.html - I only get the inline html template in the modal.

Does that help clear up the question?