# ng-show and ng-if fail to display content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, angular-ng-if

Trying to build a simple tab. Content in Tab 0 shows and hides as expected, however, Tab 1 is only ever blank, despite the scope updating true when Tab 1 is clicked.

Primarily, the controller is kicked off on a wrapper div:

```
<div ng-controller="AdvancedSettingsController as settings">
```

Here's the controller:

```
function AdvancedSettingsController($scope) {

    //setting tab name, and initial booleans
    $scope.tab = [
        {
            title : "Domains",
            active : true
        },
        { 
            title: "Locale",
            active : false 
        }
    ];

}
```

And the ng-click listener:

```
AdvancedSettingsController.prototype.tabs = function (o) {
    //set both tab active booleans to false
    for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.tab.length - 1; i++) {
        $scope.tab[i].active = false;
    }

    //set active tab boolean to true
    $scope.tab[o].active = true;

}
```

And now, the tab object looped with ng-repeat - settings.tabs($index) is passing the index to the function above:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="tab in settings.tab">
   <a data-ng-click="settings.tabs($index)">
      {{tab.title}}
   </a>
</li>
```

Content is held in 2 divs, with ifs:

```
<div data-ng-if="settings.tab[0].active">
   Content 1, true by default. Hides and shows as nav is toggled.
</div>

<div data-ng-if="settings.tab[1].active">
   Content 2, false by default. Never shows as nav is toggled.
</div>
```

Lastly, Chrome never updates the if:
      ngIf: settings.tab[1].active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html you are trying to access data through settings.tab and settings.tabs and I don't see where you define that settings...

Following the code you posted here I created this solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raMbGr

```
<li ng-repeat="t in tab">
  <a ng-click="tabs($index)">
    {{t.title}}
  </a>
</li>

<div ng-if="tab[0].active">
  Content 1, true by default. Hides and shows as nav is toggled.
</div>

<div ng-if="tab[1].active">
  Content 2, false by default. Never shows as nav is toggled.
</div>
```

Comment: settings is established in the wrapping div with ng-controller="AdvancedSettingsController as settings". What I'm seeing is that the code is theoretically correct - but that there is something else causing my woes. We have an atypical angular set-up, and I wonder how much it's affecting this. I have noticed some other tricky things that aren't working as expected in my company's angular deployment (see non-related post about ng-template: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629290/angular-directive-templateurl-wont-render-on-script-tag ). Perhaps I'll start a separate thread. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question, which is not evident here, is that I had an extra closing div in my first tab. It was closing out the ng-if and then there was broken mark-up.

My code looked like this:

```
<div ng-if="tab[0].active">
   <div>
      Content 1, true by default. Hides and shows as nav is toggled.
   </div>
   **</div>**
</div>

<div ng-if="tab[1].active">
  Content 2, false by default. Never shows as nav is toggled.
</div>
```

The ng-if was not closing at the right spot - so despite the $scope updating, the html was broken. So. annoying.